# What is the object-oriented idea I'm trying to get at with my scenario?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a scenario where I've made a class, call it `myClass`, and I've realized I need another class, call it `myOtherClass`, which will be used inside of `myClass` but not outside of it. I haven't taken a Computer Science class for years, so I can't remember the terminology for what I'm trying to get at. There is no inheritance going on; just that `myClass` uses `myOtherClass`, in fact builds a tree of `myOtherClass` objects, and I want to encapsulate everything properly.

What is the concept I need to be following and what is it in C++ specifically? Please let me know if I need to try and make this question more clear.

Comment: maybe you refer to composition?

Comment: The inner, nested class is an implementation detail of the outer class, or at least it sounds that way. If so then one alternative to nesting classes is to use good old-fashioned separate compilation, where internally in the implementation file for `myClass` you can define `myOtherClass` in an anonymous (unnamed) namespace. For a header only module you can use a namespace naming convention like `detail` or `impl` contains implementation code, or, with header only module class nesting becomes more attractive, so might go for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a nested class.

```
class myClass
{
   class myOtherClass {...}; // myOtherClass is a nested class inside
                             // myClass.

   myOtherClass a;           // a is member variable of myClass.
                             // Its type is myOtherClass.
};
```

Comment: Where is the conventional place to put that other class? Above the `public` and `private`?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the nested class. if it is purely an implementation detail, it belongs in the `private` section. Sometimes they are in the `public` section too.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like composition. The class owns a private member:

```
class Edible {};

class Food
{
private:
    Edible eds;
};
```

Note that this is in some ways similar to private inheritance (although as you mention you're building a tree of them, composition is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

MyClass is composed of a tree of MyOtherClass objects. The design pattern is one of composition. If you implemented a templated Tree class, your code might look like this:

```
#include "MyOtherClass.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
 MyClass();
 ~MyClass();
private:
 Tree<MyOtherClass> m_tree;
};
```